# Switching between integrated and discrete graphics on alienware 14?

Tags: performance, intel-graphics, nvidia-graphics-card, switchable-graphics

I recently received a new alienware 14 in the mail and was having some issues switching between integrated and discrete graphics. When I used the inbuilt benchmark tests in Just Cause 2 i pulled in a modest 15 FPS at low settings. I was wondering why the performance was so low but then I saw that the game was using the integrated intel graphics instead of the discrete nvidia card. I tried to hit fn + f5 but the message "your graphics solution is automatically configured for optimal performance." I have also changed the preferred graphics processor to the nivida one in the nvidia control panel. Is there a way to force the computer to use the nvidia processor instead of the integrated one?

Many thanks,

Nicholas

If it helps:
COMPUTER:
Alienware 14 |
Intel Core i7 4700MQ 2.42 GHz turbo boost up to 3.6 | 
NVIDIA GeForce 750M with 1 GB GDDR5 | 
8 GB RAM | 
750 GB HDD 7200 RPM

Comment: run OpenHardwareMonitor and look if the nVIDIA is used: http://openhardwaremonitor.org/

Comment: Here is the screenshot from OpenHardwareMonitor:

Comment: http://bayimg.com/eApPpaafm

Comment: from the picture you can see that the nVIDIA is in use.

Comment: So is it just that the nvidia processor does not work very well? because I am not quite getting the performance I was hoping for when i purchased the computer...

Comment: laptop chips of GPUs are much slower compared to the desktop PC cards.